# Append 2nd Child, Change its colour, innerhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Using the example below, I want to alter the colour of the second letter.

HTML code contains:

```
 <div class="sideNavLogo" onload="changeColour()">My Wedding Website</div>
```

Javascript contains:

```
function changeColour(){
    var str = document.getElementById("sideNavLogo").innerHTML;
    var result = str.fontcolor("green");
    DocumentTimeline.getElementById("sideNavLogo").append;
}
```

There been many various versions of my "changeColour" function yet none of them worked. This is the latest one. I'd prefer to use Javascript(not jQuery).

Basically, what I want to do is the 2nd letter of "My" which is "y" to be green.

For those which will question "why not jQuery" is that I prefer to get a grasp on fundamentals first rather than use the library and have no clue what it does.

Thank you so much for reading all of this! :D And second thanks goes to those which are willing to answer :)

Comment: Personally I would use a span and some CSS, from what you've shown here it doesn't seem like you need to use JS at all. Is that an option or do you need to use JS?

Comment: js cannot apply css directly to a letter - it would have to wrap it in an element and then apply css to that - so rather than doing that and getting a flash of unstyled content whilst it loads, why not just apply the span directly to the html rather than using js to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I mentioned in the comments, using CSS rather than JS:

```css
.sideNavLogo {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.sideNavLogo span{
  color: #0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideNavLogo">M<span>y</span> Wedding Website</div>
```

You don't mention animation, but your JS looks like you may be attempting it, so here's the CSS way to do some simple animation:

```css
.sideNavLogo {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sideNavLogo span {
  color: #0e0;
  /* 
    This animation will run imediately for 2 seconds
    the "forwards" means that it will remain in the 
    final state of the animation, e.g. remain green 
  */
  animation: colorChange linear 2s forwards;
}

/* The animation we're applying to the span */
@keyframes colorChange {
  0% {
    color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #0e0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sideNavLogo">M<span>y</span> Wedding Website</div>
```